# How do bindings work with syntax objects created by module macros in Racket?

Tags: macros, racket

I have completed [this tutorial](https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/intro.html) from the book *Beautiful Racket*. The tutorial shows how to use Racket to implement a simple stack-based calculator mini-language. After having finished the tutorial, I am still confused about how it works, specifically how the bindings work in the macros.

Here is the code that defines the reader and expander for the "stacker" language:

`stacker.rkt`

```
#lang br/quicklang

(define (read-syntax path port)
  (define src-lines (port->lines port))
  (define src-datums (format-datums '(handle ~a) src-lines))
  (define module-datum `(module stacker-mod "stacker.rkt"
                          ,@src-datums))
  (datum->syntax #f module-datum))
(provide read-syntax)

(define-macro (stacker-module-begin HANDLE_EXPR ...)
  #'(#%module-begin
     HANDLE_EXPR ...
     (display (first stack))))
(provide (rename-out [stacker-module-begin #%module-begin]))

(define stack empty)

(define (pop-stack!)
  (define arg (first stack))
  (set! stack (rest stack))
  arg)

(define (push-stack! arg)
  (set! stack (cons arg stack)))

(define (handle [arg #f])
  (cond
    [(number? arg) (push-stack! arg)]
    [(or (equal? + arg) (equal? * arg))
     (define op-result (arg (pop-stack!) (pop-stack!)))
     (push-stack! op-result)]))
(provide handle)

(provide + *)
```

Here is the code that uses the stacker language:

`stacker-test.rkt`

```
#lang reader "stacker.rkt"
4
8
+
3
*
```

The result of running "stacker-test.rkt" is that the integer "36" is printed to the console (the result of (4 + 8) * 3)

Here is my understanding of what happens when I run "stacker-test.rkt":

1. Racket sees the line `#lang reader "stacker.rkt"` and finds the function `read-syntax` from the file "stacker.rkt". It passes a port for reading the file to that function.
2. `read-syntax` reads the file and puts each line into a datum representing a call to some `handle` function (for example, `'(handle 4)`. These datums are then put into a datum that represents a `module`, and that datum is stored in a syntax-object which is returned by the `read-syntax` function
3. Racket extracts the datum from the syntax object, turns it back into actual code and executes it. The `module` function finds the `#%module-begin` macro (aka `stacker-module-begin`) in "stacker.rkt" and invokes it, passing in the same `handle` datums that were arguments to the `module` function.
4. The `stacker-module-begin` macro creates a syntax-object. The code represented by that syntax object, when executed, will invoke the `#%module-begin` macro from the `br/quicklang` language. The arguments to that invocation of `#%module-begin` will be the same `handle` expressions that were arguments to `stacker-module-begin`, plus an expression that displays the top of the `stack` variable. `stacker-module-begin` returns the syntax object it created back to Racket
5. Racket executes the code represented by the syntax-object it just received. That code invokes `#%module-begin` from `br/quicklang` and passes to it a bunch of expressions to process. `#%module-begin` returns some syntax object, which Racket again executes. Eventually Racket actually executes the following code:

```
handle(4)
handle(8)
handle(+)
handle(3)
handle(*)
(display (first stack))
```

What I am confused about are how Racket knows the bindings for `handle` and `stack` when it executes this code. I can think of two ways:

1. When `stacker-module-begin` created a syntax object, it included the bindings for `handle` and `stacker` (as defined later in the file) as part of the syntax object's context, so Racket had those bindings when executing the code.
2. Racket has already executed the entire "stacker.rkt" file, and so it has all of the exported definitions already in its own context, independent of bindings packaged with the syntax object.

My first assumption was that #1 was the case. I thought that was the point of syntax objects and macros - they let you associate variable bindings with code so you have the bindings when you run the code in a different context. But this doesn't make sense because the process only works if I include the line `(provide handle)` in "stacker.rkt". I would think that if the binding for `handle` were included in the syntax object, there would be no need to export the definition.

So then I thought that #2 was the case. But then I realized that `stack` is not ever exported via `provide`. So the binding for `stack` must be included in the syntax object created by `stacker-module-begin`. But if `stacker-module-begin` can include the binding for `stack`, why didn't it also include the definition for `handle`?

Comment: `read-syntax` returns a new module that inherits from "stacker.rkt"; the only symbols it can see when the body of the module is compiled and executed are the ones provided by "stacker.rkt".

Comment: To elaborate @Shawn's answer: it's `"stacker.rkt"` in (define module-datum `(module stacker-mod "stacker.rkt" ,@src-datums)).

Comment: That doesn't explain why "handle" needs to be exported with "provide" but "stack" does not. Both identifiers are defined within "stacker rkt", so I would expect either both of them to need to be exported or neither of them.

Comment: Wait, I think I understand. The HANDLE_EXP code is evaluated with a different context than the code that follows it. HANDLE_EXP has the context of the syntax object created by "read-syntax", which only has access to identifiers that were provided. The code following the HANDLE_EXP has the context of the syntax object created by "stacker-module-begin", and that has access to anything within "stacker.rkt".

Comment: At some point I will do some testing to confirm my understanding. If it's correct, then I will turn it into an answer. But if either of you want to provide an answer first, then I can accept that answer instead

Comment: `stack` doesn't need to be provided; it's not used by `stacker-test.rkt`, just by the functions and macros provided by `"stacker.rkt"` module, which since they're defined in that module have it in their scope.

Comment: I think you're really over complicating things and going down the wrong track with syntax objects. You should be thinking in terms of modules and scope of identifiers instead.